# How to check what LoadRunner Controller is currently doing?[TruClient]

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, vugen

I have a script which was developed using TruClient for a web application. When I'am going through this test manually everything is working fine. When I'am doing the same test using TruClient in Virtual User Generator everything is fine as well(automated script is written properly).

The problem starts when I'm using LoadRunner Controller. From specified moment all the tests are failed(circa after 40 passed iterations/10 Vusers).

My question is: is there any possibility to check what was wrong on the website? Maybe take some screenshots or something?

(Controller 12.02.0.0 Build 1258)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you know about this, but this is where I debug TruClient (and all) scripts which are running in Controller mode.
1) Goto the "Run" tab
2) Double click on the group of the user you want to look at.
3) Right click on the user you want to look at (some could be running or failed)
4) Select "Show User Log"

This will show the console output of the script so will show you then a step starts or finishes, and any LR.log statements you have scripts.
You can enable get screenshots on error (I think it may be enabled by default) in the run-time settings, but I haven't had any luck with the option in there to get a screenshot of every step.
If you restart a user then your logs will be overwritten.

Comment: I have never heard about this. Thanks a lot for a hint! I will check it and get back to you with an answer.